# showing everything in a mongod database

Tags: mongodb

once you have executed the "use" command, how do you show everything in that database?

```
> use library
switched to db library
```

what do I do to see everything in there?

I do this and all I see is a blank line:

```
> show collections
books
system.indexes
> use books
switched to db books
> show collections
```

Comment: Do you mean show every document in a collection? If so, `db.book.find({})` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is not valid here. when you hit command 
"use library" 
It took you to library database.Then you hit 
"show collections" 
it will show you collections "**inside that library database"**
Collections are  like tables in RDBMS.

Now if you want to see data inside your books collection.You need to hit 
db.books.find()

what mistake you are doing is again you hit "use books"
this command will take you to books database (if not created then it will create by default and if you didn't add any collection it will be removed as well)

So basically You are entering to a blank database having no collection.